# which component is available in rich faces to continuously call back end server method like ajax functionality

Tags: java, richfaces

which component is available in rich faces to continuously call back end server method like Ajax functionality

please give any suggestions if u have

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a4j:poll is one of the way how you can organize the periodical polling of server data and updating the page. a4j:poll is a standard RichFaces Ajax component. Thus, you can use the same approach as for a4j:commandButton for example.
for more details very the link

```
http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/poll.jsf
```